# How to ignore output for a parameterized Ruby system call

Tags: ruby, io-redirection

I found [some code](https://porkrind.org/missives/calling-applescript-from-ruby/) that allows me to run an Applescript from Ruby via system calls:

```
system 'osascript', *script.split(/\n/).map { |line| ['-e', line] }.flatten
```

It works great, but it's not exactly what I need.

I want to modify the system call so that standard output is ignored.

I started by adding `1>/dev/null` parameter:

```
system 'osascript', *script.split(/\n/).map { |line| ['-e', line] }.flatten, "1>/dev/null"
```

This didn't work as the third parameter appears to be ignored.

Then I removed the parameterized call and used string interpolation:

```
system "osascript #{*script.split(/\n/).map { |line| ['-e', line] }.flatten} 1>/dev/null"
```

which produced a syntax error.

Then I tried various attempts at moving things around, which mostly produced other syntax errors.

What's the correct syntax for ignoring system output in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be easier if you switched from `Kernel#system` to [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html). The methods in Open3 give you convenient control over stdin, stdout, and stderr without having to mess around, you could even feed your script into `osascript` through stdin rather than splitting it apart and using multiple `-e` switches.

Something like this perhaps:

```
out, error, status = Open3.capture3('osascript', stdin_data: script)
```

And if you want to ignore stdout and stderr, use placeholder variables:

```
_, _, status = Open3.capture3('osascript', stdin_data: script)
*_, status = Open3.capture3('osascript', stdin_data: script)
```

And if you don't care about stdout, stderr, or the status:

```
Open3.capture3('osascript', stdin_data: script)
```

But your conscience should tell you to at least check the status.

Comment: I've actually used Open3 before but wasn't trying it because I thought the `-e` switches were necessary and I wasn't sure how to work that in. You showed me I can just pass the script directly to Open3.capture3 without any manipulation or flags. I don't know if it'll cause trouble for other cases, but I can confirm it works when creating a multiline email using a HEREDOC 

Comment: If you need to, you could use your `*script.split(/\n/).map { |line| ['-e', line] }.flatten` trick with `Open3.capture3` with `Open3.capture3('osascript', *script.split(/\n/).flat_map { |line| ['-e', line] }`)`.

Comment: it finally failed and guess who wasn't checking the status or std_err? --> ME. Now I have to wait until it fails again to see why. I should have listened to that conscience you were talking about :D. Others take heed!

Answer (score 3):

The available options for `system`, `exec` and `spawn` are documented in [`Kernel#spawn`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn), including those for redirection. To redirect stdout to `/dev/null` you'd use:

```
system('...', out: '/dev/null')
```

Or via [`File::NULL`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/File/Constants.html#NULL):

```
system('...', out: File::NULL)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't use this because part of my issue was how to pass the manipulation being done and using `*script.split(/\n/).map { |line| ['-e', line] }.flatten` as input. The syntax was tripping me up every time I tried to put everything in one string (corresponds to your '...'). I'm halfway doing it in my last attempt in my post, just not with the redirection parameters that you included. Good to know though